# How to fetch all goods from category and subcategories and subcategories and subcategories and etc...?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two entities in CoreData:

```
EntityGoods{
    NSString *name;
    EntityCategories *category;
}
EntityCategories{
    NSString *name;
    EntityCategories *parent;
    NSSet *childrens;
}
```

I create category with name "Fruits" and inside I create two categories "Apples" and "Bananas"
Inside "Apples" I create goods: Apples GRANNY, Apples GOLD
Inside "Bananas" I create two categories "American" and "African"
Inside "American" I create good:  Bananas BANANZA
Inside "African" I create goods: Bananas SOUTH AFRICA, Small bananas

```
Fruits-Apples->['Apples GRANNY', 'Apples GOLD']
     |-Bananas-American->['Bananas BANANZA']
             |-African->['Bananas SOUTH AFRICA', 'Bananas SMALL']
```

I want to fetch all bananas and apples from fruits.

What predicate can I use for get result like this:

[Apples GOLD, Apples GRANNY, Bananas BANANZA, Bananas SMALL, Bananas SOUTH AFRICA]

Or I want to fetch all bananas from bananas category:

[Bananas BANANZA, Bananas SMALL, Bananas SOUTH AFRICA]

I know how to fetch goods inside category:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category=%@", parentCategory]
```

But I want to fetch all goods from category and subcategories and subcategories.
Is it real?

Comment: You can create a fetch request with out predicate no?

Comment: @AnushaK, What you mean?

Comment: Just a suggestion. Why not you use SQLite for the same requirement. Using the SQL query get the required values

Comment: @AnushaK, can you please show me example of SQLite query?